# Problem with pairing device using wifi in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi, pairing

I want to pair my android device by scanning QrCode in device manager android studio.

Sometime it works but often it doesn't work.

when I scan QrCode it waits in state below

**I try ways below:**

1- Connecting to same wifi

2- Deleting all previous paired devices

3- Try to connect using pairing with code

4- Reseting android studio

and all solutions offered in stack

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Deleting of previously paired device was a solution for me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By following the 7 steps below, your problem will be solved definitely:

1. You should add **adb** to your environment variables. open your environment
   variable and add ***Your-SDK=path*\platform-tools** to environment variables Path.
2. In your device open **Wireless debugging** under **developer options**.(if developer options not exists in your settings you should activate developer mode)
3. in wireless debugging tap on **Pair device with pairing code**.
4. in your Android studio open Terminal and write commands below in terminal.
5. adb pair Ip-address:port *(get Ip address from dialog below)*

[image]

6. Insert wifi pairing code. **(get pairing code from dialog above)**
7. adb connect IP-address:port **(get Ip address & port from dialog below)**.
   You've done successfully. congratulations

[image]

Comment: Why does the GUI not work if the solution is this simple?!

Comment: `Successfully paired to 192.168.0.162:41609
failed to connect to '192.168.0.162:41609': Connection refused`
I see no options to wi-fi debug after pairing.

Comment: This paired my device successfully. But I still can't see a way to "run" the app on my device since the device doesn't show up as active on the device manager.

Comment: @Psijic you have to use different ports to pair and to connect to the device; in the answer above, the port 41551 is used to pair and the port 40119 is used to connect

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem like it. Now I use Android Studio Dolphin, WiFi connection works well.
Also In Windows Task Manager you can kill adb.exe and try connect your device again.